# Can water percolation pit affect RCC column and footer

Tags: concrete, foundation, drainage, water-damage, column

We have water percolation pits installed around the house to handle waste water from kitchen , washing machine and bathroom.

I worry whether this water percolation pit can affect the RCC column and footer which is my foundation  ?

The building was constructed using Framed Structure rather than load bearing wall structure

[image]

Please find photo of 4 percolation pits ( 2 feet radius ) by south side of my building

[image]

Please find photo of 2 percolation pits ( 3 feet radius ) by north side of building

[image]

- Please find the video of dry wells on the south side of the building [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tHSitIxg8Rcq8tgbv7tGf5qFfSfxhgqq/view?usp=sharing)
- Please find the video of dry wells on the north side of the building [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mITg0oWOYoWc6zaZzsQLR5ARbxEZ4W2l/view?usp=sharing)

**Sand texture:**

- It's clay
- Water table 2 ( During rainy season ) to 4 feet ( During summer )
- Ground water is saline

Here is what government geological survey says about the soil profile

[image]

Some insights into this is appreciated

### Update:

I have already made significant investments into buying the concrete cement rings and placing it.

If this is gonna be a problem , I can certainly consider buying some more land and spread out the waste water over a garden. But this is a huge investment again.

Let's say above is an option , then leaving these Percolation pit empty. I mean divert the water to elsewhere.. then may i leave the percolation pits as it is.

From my experience , I can say the water level in percolation pit goes up and down .. without any incoming water from building.

I think water gets filled into the pit by surface level acquifier.

Would this be a problem to footing and cause any differential settlement ?

Comment: yes it can have negative impact due to soil softening

Comment: I'm really worried. if you could have a look at the link(https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/252733/142629) and leave your insights .. It'd be a great help.

Comment: I believe concrete is a Porus material and the pores of it will be filled by water and by any chance if the water reaches the steel bar , it may rust and can cause it to expand and this may weaken the foundation structure ideally the ground should not be wet. that's why people usually go for sump pump , French drain etc just to keep the water away from the foundation. You can apply bitumen on the foundation walls and fill all the voids and regularly do that once in a decade just to protect the foundation.

Comment: @CuriousMan - bitumen seems to be giving peace of mind.Thanks