# Is it risky to have soak pit of septic tank near building

Tags: water, safety, water-damage, septic

I have series of soak pits connected by pipe and this soak pit takes grey water from Kitchen and bathroom only.

I have to call septic tank lorry frequently to pump out the filled up septic tank. Please know that septic tank is stand alone .. it doesn't have any soak pit/away or cesspit so far.

The grey water(Kitchen , bathroom water not toilet septic) is connected to soak pit and these soak pits never overflows or gets filled somehow it drains all the water over the night even though the ground is complete clay.

As per my calculation the total gray water output would be 2000 Litre everyday.

The water that goes to septic tank could be 700 or 800 litre per day the max.

But somehow the soak pit drains all the gray water over the night.

So I'm thinking I can construct a filter box outside of septic tank so only the overflowing water, just water comes using Effluent filter and I can direct the water into the soak pit.

As of now this soak pit's cap is not plastered air tight because water is just gray water but I can get a mason to plaster it permanently and I can get the air pipe 10 feet high so I can send the filtered water from septic tank to these soak pits.

Soak pit size is 2 feet radius and 5 feet down from ground level.

There are four sets of soak pits connected together serially.

Septic tank size is 15(L) by 7 ( W ) by 5(H)

I wonder soak pit drains all the water while septic tank couldn't.

So would it be ok?

Or it's a health risk?

Someone please enlighten me.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a diagram of your system? What is a soak pit versus tank? Why do you need to keep calling for a pump out - that suggests your tank is not working right, perhaps because of what is going into it.

Comment: @Armand - I have to pump out my septic tank frequently because it gets filled very easily. FYI this septic tank is not connected with any soak pit/away or cess pit. It's stand alone septic tank.

Comment: @Armand - The ground is clay and water table is very high

Comment: This question is related with this [one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/252820/142629)